# Python crawler: always fetch the content of the first page

Tags: python, python-requests, web-crawler

python: Some problems encountered when using request crawler, always fetch the content of the first page.

I want to use https://jfrog.com/blog/ to practice crawling. According to my idea, when I want to crawl the content of different pages, I should change the number of pages in the URL. Fortunately this URL includes the page number, something like https://jfrog.com/blog/?pagenum=2.
But when I change the number of pages in a loop, the crawled content is always the content of the first page. When I change the number of pages in the URL in the browser, the content in the browser doesn't change either. In the browser, I see the status code is 304, which may be caused by a cache problem. So how do I use code to get the content of different pages? Below is my code:

```
import requests
import json
import time
import datetime
from lxml import etree
from tqdm import tqdm
import os
import random

headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36 Edg/96.0.1054.29"}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    all_articles = []
    base_url = 'https://jfrog.com/blog/?pagenum={page_number}'
    for page_num in range(1,10):
        print('Page {}...'.format(page_num))
        visit_url = base_url.format(page_number=page_num)
        print(base_url.format(page_number=page_num))
        res = requests.get(visit_url,headers=headers)
        print(res.status_code)
        text = res.content.decode('utf-8')
        html = etree.HTML(text)
        # print(text)
        for article_index in range(1, 11):
            article_name_pattern = '//*[@id="postsWrap"]/article[{article_index}]/header/div/div/div[2]/a/h3/text()'
            article_link_pattern = '//*[@id="postsWrap"]/article[{article_index}]/header/div/div/div[2]/a/@href'
            article_time_pattern = '//*[@id="postsWrap"]/article[{article_index}]/header/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/p/text()'
            try:
                article_name = html.xpath(article_name_pattern.format(article_index=article_index))[0]
                article_link = html.xpath(article_link_pattern.format(article_index=article_index))[0]
                article_time = html.xpath(article_time_pattern.format(article_index=article_index))[0]
                d_item = {'article_name':article_name, 'article_link':article_link, 'article_time':article_time}
                all_articles.append(d_item)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                with open('../save/log.txt', 'a+') as f:
                    f.write('Page-{0} Article-{1} Failed!\n'.format(page_num, article_index))
                f.close()
        time.sleep(random.randint(5,10))
        with open('../save/Jfrog_blog_articles_1.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(all_articles,f)
        f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue you're facing is not related to your code, but rather to the website itself. If changing the page number in the URL doesn't change the content displayed in the browser, then it's likely that the website doesn't support pagination through URL parameters.

One possible solution could be to use a headless browser like Selenium to interact with the website and simulate clicking on the pagination buttons. This would allow you to navigate to different pages and scrape their content.

Comment: This site is really different from what I have encountered before，I researched Selenium which you mentioned and it has solved my problem, thanks!